# Unzip command extracts all files without directory structure

Tags: linux, zip, unzip

I have a .zip file that came from an Azure App Service custom backup. I have downloaded this file to a Linux container and run `unzip a.zip`. Note that I am **not** passing the `-j` flag.

The result is that it extracts thousands of files into my current directory, entirely ignoring the directory structure of the .zip file. No directories are created as a result of this operation.

The desired result would be to extract the zip file maintaining the directory structure of the zip file, with all files located in the directories they belong-to.

I have downloaded the same file in Windows. Its MD5 hash is the same as the Linux container. I can perfectly see, and extract, the entire directory structure of the zip file in WinRar, 7Zip, and even Windows Explorer.

How can I unzip the .zip file in the Linux container and maintain its directory structure?

Comment: An example filename created by the `unzip` command is 'fs\site\wwwroot\readme.txt'.

Comment: If you are saying that unzip creates a file called `fs\site\wwwroot\readme.txt` it suggests your zip file has used backslashes for path separators. That is not allowed. Can you post the output from running `unzip -l a.zip`.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/166159/convert-a-windows-created-zip-to-linux-internal-paths-issue

Comment: @pmqs You are correct. What is shocking to me is that it's Azure doing this, and even more shocking, they do this from a Linux app service.